# Something fires update triggers

Tags: trigger, workflow, process-builder, governorlimits

I have problem with something working only on my org, this thing causes my triggers to fire update on Case triggers and it causes SOQL limit exception. I cannot find what it could be, I have everything set like we have on ours Validation org, and tests passes correctly on validators, and fails (due to SOQL queries) on my org.

I already:

- deleted all the Triggers from org
- deployed fresh from repo
- checked Process Builder and Workflows

Everything is same as on validator. What else should I check?

Comment: Do you have some packages installed from the AppExchange?

Comment: Yes I have: Salesforce Connected Apps, Adobe Sign, OfficeIntegration, all of the are also installed on validators orgs.

Comment: another possibility is you have testmethods that rely on seeAllData=true and the Validator org has way more data than your org; and there is some code that is looping through resulting objects and doing soql inside of loops.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but not, we don't have see all data tests.